# How to get nested loop to move to next set of data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet (CAT) where I'm trying to copy 15 rows of 8 columns of data into one row in the other worksheet (Transpose).  I have multiple nested loops where I need one of my loops to move on to the next set of 15 rows in the CAT worksheet (rowIndex).  Instead the code goes back to the first 2 to 16 rows and fills in the same 15 rows each time.  I've tried multiple iterations of adding rowIndex = rowIndex + 15, but this doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

```
    For rowTranspose = 2 To 3 'move down one row when first row is filled in Transpose sheet
       For colTranspose = 8 To 120 Step 8 'write data from columns 8 to 15 and rows 2 to 16 (colIndex, rowIndex) in columns 8 through 120 of Transpose sheet
           For rowIndex = 2 To 16 'loop through rows 2 through 16
               For colIndex = 8 To 15 'loop through columns 8 through 15
                    Transpose.Cells(rowTranspose, colTranspose) = CAT.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex) 'copy CAT worksheet values to rowTranspose and colTranspose values
                    colTranspose = colTranspose + 1 'move the columns over so that the CAT info copies to the correct column
               Next colIndex
           Next rowIndex
       Next colTranspose
       rowIndex = rowIndex + 15
    Next rowTranspose
```

Comment: Four loops, `colTranspose = colTranspose + 1`, and `rowIndex = rowIndex + 15` are code smells. Could you just explain what you're trying to do? i.e. what is your setup on the `CAT` worksheet, what cells are you copying, and how should the `Transpose` sheet look after copying?

Comment: In CAT, I have data in the range of I2:P27151 that is in 15 row chunks.  For the first 15 rows of that range, I would like to place them in the Transpose worksheet in one row in order.  So the 15 rows from CAT should appear sequentially in row 2 of the Transpose worksheet.  Once I've copied all 15 rows, I'd like to move to row 3 of the Transpose worksheet and copy the next 15 rows in the CAT worksheet, and so on through row 27,151.

Comment: Ok I think I get your setup with that explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `rowIndex` is set by the loop so `rowIndex = rowIndex + 15` does nothing. Add another variable called `rowOffset` and add that to 'rowIndex'.

```vb
    rowOffset = 0
    For rowTranspose = 2 To 3 'move down one row when first row is filled in Transpose sheet
        For colTranspose = 8 To 120 Step 8 'write data from columns 8 to 15 and rows 2 to 16 (colIndex, rowIndex) in columns 8 through 120 of Transpose sheet
            For rowIndex = 2 To 16 'loop through rows 2 through 16
                For colIndex = 8 To 15 'loop through columns 8 through 15
                    Transpose.Cells(rowTranspose, colTranspose) = CAT.Cells(rowIndex + rowOffset, colIndex) 'copy CAT worksheet values to rowTranspose and colTranspose values
                    colTranspose = colTranspose + 1 'move the columns over so that the CAT info copies to the correct column
                Next colIndex
            Next rowIndex
        Next colTranspose
        rowOffset = rowOffset + 15
    Next rowTranspose
```